# remove rows containing certain data

Tags: r, dataframe

In my data frame the first column is a factor and I want to delete rows that have a certain value of *factorname* (when the value is present). I tried:

```
df <- df[-grep("factorname",df$parameters),]
```

Which works well when the targeted factor name is present. However if the *factorname* is absent, this command destroys the data frame, leaving it with 0 rows. So I tried:

```
df <- df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) {df$parameters == "factorname"}),]
```

that does not remove the offending lines. How can I test for the presence of *factorname* and remove the line if *factorname* is present?

Comment: The danger you are illustrating also applies to using the `-which(...)` strategy.

Comment: Perhaps success with `df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) {x['parameters'] == "factorname"}),]` although that seems fairly clunky. You would be testing just one value with each row rather than sending an entire vector against "==" with each apply-iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
df[ which( ! df$parameter %in% "factorname") , ]
```

(Used `%in%` since it would generalize better to multiple exclusion criteria.) Also possible:

```
df[ !grepl("factorname", df$parameter) , ]
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `df[df$parameters!="factorname",]` be enough? What added complexity am I missing here?

Comment: Yeah. Overlooking the obvious. What thelatemail said.

Answer (score 2):

```
l<-sapply(iris,function(x)is.factor(x)) # test for the factor variables
>l
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
       FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE 

m<-iris[,names(which(l=="TRUE"))]) #gives the data frame of factor variables only
iris[iris$Species !="setosa",] #generates the data with Species other than setosa 



   > head(iris[iris$Species!="setosa",])
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
56          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
```

Comment: Is all that `sapply` and subsetting really necessary for such a simple query? If I was starting out with R I'd be utterly confused by the time I got to the key line.

Comment: Agree; I thought OP was looking for checking for all the factor variables